# where is the "window" object defined or created in firefox source code

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, window

I'm reading the Firefox source code and I would like to know how to create some global functions.

I can't find where the window object is created or how to define some global objects to be accessed by scripts.

I would like to know where to begin or at least where the window object is defined and created, thanks!

Comment: You are reading firefox source code? or a javascript source code?

Comment: the firefox source code. read the javascript engine source code, it won't set up the global object, it must have been set in somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `window` object is mostly defined in [nsGlobalWindow.cpp](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/4e4878620bb5/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.cpp). The public methods/properties belong to nsIDOMWindow, nsIDOMJSWindow, nsIDOMEventTarget, nsIDOMStorageIndexedDB and some other interfaces (look for `NS_INTERFACE_MAP_ENTRY` macros but not all of them refer to public interfaces).

In addition, as any DOM object it can have expando properties (properties set by script). Some of these expando properties are set automatically when the DOM wrapper is created ([nsWindowSH](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/4e4878620bb5/dom/base/nsDOMClassInfo.cpp#l4957) class). In particular, components implementing [nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer) can set properties at that stage, or components listening to [content-document-global-created](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Documents) notification.

Comment: thank you very much! this solved my problem! and those hyper link, how kind of you. thx~

Comment: I stumbled across this thread, and now I'm curious - how does the Javascript I type in my `<script>` tag, talk to the C++ code in Firefox's source code?

Comment: @Imray: Currently this happens via [WebIDL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/WebIDL_bindings). There are interface definitions that determine which methods are exposed to JavaScript and how these are mapped to C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

`window` is the global object.

**Anything**  defined out of a scope will be put into `window`

---

So if you do (in the global scope):

```
var myVar = 123;

alert(myVar); // alerts 123
alert(window.myVar); // ALSO alerts 123
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but I mean where is the global "window" object defined or created in the firefox source code.

Comment: @user1108486 It would not be in the firefox code. ff is using a javascript engine.

Comment: yes, but by using the javascript engin, one must set up a global object which being the "window" object.

Answer (score 0):

Have I really mis-understood? Are you writing something in JavaScript?

If so you can append to the window object simply by declaring a variable in the global scope.

```
window.myvar = 123123;
```

Indeed, if you haven't wrapped your code in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) then you can simply do:

```
var myvar = "some value";
```

Comment: thx, but I mean finding where the window is set in the mozilla source code.